# How Call routed in F5 Box from => Client - Virtual Server - Pool - Pool Member and back to client

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip, client-server

How Call routed in F5 Box from => Client - Virtual Server - Pool - Pool Member and back to client.

What are the different way of response possible from Pool member back to client like 
      i)directly to client from pool member or 
      ii) via F5

Can somebody pl explain on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options available, depending on your architecture and your traffic needs. There are layer 2 modes available, but I'll focus here on layer 3.

1. Routed. In routed mode, you have routes for clientside traffic and serverside traffic. In this mode, client IP is passed as source address from BIG-IP to the server. This assumes your servers then have routes back through BIG-IP for those clients.

   2. Natted. In natted mode, you have routes for clientside traffic to get to BIG-IP and serverside traffic, but not routes from servers back to clients, so a nat address (most likely a snat in BIG-IP terminology) is used for servers to route traffic back through the BIG-IP. This means the client IP is no longer passed as the client's source address on the packet, so if it is necessary for the server for audit/stats purposes, you'll need to inject it in an appropriate header.
   3. nPath. In this mode, the BIG-IP has a virtual server with the same IP as a loopback on the server, so traffic is routed to BIG-IP, then to the server, and the return path bypasses the BIG-IP altogether on the way back to the client. This is common with streaming services where you want the intelligence in the BIG-IP without the streaming throughput impacting the box.

If there is a particular scenario you are interested in, I can provide more clarity for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Your Answer Clarified exactly the requirement, Can you pl provide some more info on layer 2